# Play youtube videos-ipad

Tags: ipad, video, youtube, playback

In my application i want to play the Youtube URL(ipad).I'm using the below code.It simply show me a White screen

Youtube url is:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x61GMbKwMkE

This is my code:

```
NSString *embed = @"\
<html><head>\
<style type=\"text/css\">\
body {\
background-color: transparent;\
color: white;\
}\
</style>\
</head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
<embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
width=320 height=460></embed>\
</body></html>";
NSString *embedURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:embed,appDelegate.videoURL];  
NSLog(@"\n\n\n\n Myurl==%@   %@\n\n\n",embedURL,appDelegate.videoURL);
[[WebView.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setScrollEnabled:NO];
[WebView loadHTMLString:embedURL baseURL:nil];
```

I'm creating and connecting UIWebView in XIB.

Anyone Guide me to do this

Thanks For your consideration and effort

Comment: Check this link this might be help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585643/youtube-videos-on-iphone-phonegap-app/10590537#10590537

Answer (score 1):

Flash is not supported in iOS. Check out [the new embed code for YouTube videos](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html) that will automatically choose the correct player for each environment.

Comment: I have no idea why this was down-voted.  This is the correct answer and that article is clear and straightforward.