# youtube videos on iphone phonegap app

Tags: iphone, video, youtube, cordova

I'm sorry to come back to this topic again, but i'm really frustrated!! I've read every  resource i've found, googling around the web, but i couldn't come up with a definitive answer to my problem.

**Problem description**
I'm creating an iphone app with phonegap 1.0. In this app, one tab is dedicated to a rss feed from my youtube channel and i want my users to be able to play these videos, after clicking on a specific entry. 
Question: is it possible? best solution would be to play the video inside the app, but displaying a thumbnail image and redirecting the user to native youtube app is also acceptable (even though in this case i want the control back to the original app when youtube finishes to play the video).

**Tried solutions**
Searching on the web I found several solutions and people say that these solutions work for them, but none of them work for me!

- use an "object" tag, i end up with a white screen

  ```
  <object id="video" width="296" height="100%" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/gDjb9RVMF4c" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
      <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
      <param name="src" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/gDjb9RVMF4c" />
  </object>
  ```
- using an "embed" tag, i end up with a white screen

  ```
  <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/gDjb9RVMF4c" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="280" height="100%"></embed>
  ```
- i also tried a "video" tag, but as far as i understood, this is still not possible.

I'm really sorry if i missed a solution already written somewhere, but trust me ... i did my homework before askying :-)
Thx!!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a nice tutorial Which Saved my Day

http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2012/01/24/embed-a-youtube-video-iframe-in-phonegap-app/

Also i m posting some codes For a quick Access.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>YouTube video</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
        <script src="phonegap-1.2.0.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/9HDeEbJyNK8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    </body>
</html>
```

Then make the following changes in Phonegap.plist

```
MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction: NO
AllowInlineMediaPlayback: YES
OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView: YES
ExternalHosts
          *.youtube.com
          *.ytimg.com
```

Video will play on your Simulator Also.

Comment: This works on the simulator; however, when I build the app using build.phonegap.com and view it on my Andriod, the videos won't play. Any idea why?

Comment: Yes , I also faced same issue in Android Device. What i done is Taken a `Web-view` and called the Link With full-screen video-play.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from using `<iframe> ... </iframe>` you also need to set the property `OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView` to `YES` in your `PhoneGap.plist`. This would show and play the video inside the PhoneGap application itself. It is tried and tested.

Comment: where should i write OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView to YES if i am using Cordova plugin for Phonegap android

Answer (score 3):

You could try embedding the YouTube video as an iframe, I believe that is the recommended way to do it now:

http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385"  frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

Comment: unfortunately this isn't working either... when i open the iphone simulator i don't even see my app, but i'm automatically redirected to safari (without pushing or doing anything)!

Comment: That sounds like another issue, not related to this, I think.

Comment: i finally understood what the problem was: videos don't work in the iphone simulator!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [component](http://www.akravets.com/posts/sencha-iphone-and-youtube-videos) I've end up using in my app. Done with a help of [YouTube iFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).