# Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.youtube.com" from accessing a frame with origin "file://"

Tags: cordova, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I have a URL for youtube :

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" ng-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/s7gJ74ARN84" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

If i use this in my local html file it plays well. But when i paste the same in a phonegap ios app html page and run that in ios simulator it shows below error just as i click the video:

```
Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.youtube.com" from accessing a frame with origin "file://".  

The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "file". Protocols must match.
```

**Solution:**

**It was not working in simulator but working in mobile and that was my ultimate goal.**

Comment: Were you able to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

@Manish,
since you have already dealt with the CORS issue, the error your a getting says:

> The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being
>   accessed has a protocol of "file". Protocols must match.

Since it is not CORS, have you gotten rid of the iframe? If that works, perhaps what you need is a hidden `<div>`.

Jesse

Comment: i didn't get your point can u pls give example reference to my youtube video

Answer (score -1):

@Manish,

it appears you have the [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) problem. You can can add to your [config.xml](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start/blob/master/www/config.xml)  `<access origin="*"/>`.

Jesse

Comment: this does not seem to help (at least in iOS 9.3, cordova 6.4.0, cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.0)

Answer (score -3):

Hey this just a very Small Problem

your link is this => "https://www.youtube.com/embed/s7gJ74ARN84"

But you just have to change it to

this link "//www.youtube.com/embed/s7gJ74ARN84"

Remember when you try to load secure content in your site just remove protocol from link

Comment: tried this `<iframe width="854" height="510" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/bAQq2mENhR4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>` and got this error  `Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server. file://www.youtube.com/embed/bAQq2mENhR4`

Comment: in jsfiddle even `<iframe width="854" height="510" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/bAQq2mENhR4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>` working fine

Comment: try this link it seem to be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585643/youtube-videos-on-iphone-phonegap-app + https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: Problem was that in IOS simulator it was not running but in mobile its running and that is my ultimate target :)

Comment: Glad you worked it out...if you changed any settings please post the solution

Comment: Doesn't that occur because it automatically matches the protocol? So `//url.com` would be`file://url.com` if the original page is `file://index.html`